# Asp.net Core Multi-tenant with Token Server

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, multi-tenant

This is how I have designed my architecture:

- Token Server - Only Captures Username and Password does not hold the users tenant. So I am not tied to a token provider.
- API - Has Tenant, Users Related to Tenant. User Id matches User Id from Token Server (subject claim)

Now there is lots of answers around determining the tenant, I have solved this issue by looking at url of the api call, but how do a determine that the user is valid for the tenant taking into account the token has no tenant information as the token server does not hold this information. Via a middle ware? custom auth attribute? My problem cant be unique I just cant find any information on the topic. I find loads about the token server hosting the tenant information.

I am doing this in ASP.NET CORE 3.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should hold the tenant id or name in the token server as a user claim. Because as tokens produced in the token server, they can't be altered or add information to them in your application.